# How to access Java API methods through command prompt?

Tags: java, command-prompt

Is there a way to access the Java API methods through command prompt?

like accessing the methods of String class, accessing the methods of Integer class. etc etc.

this will serve as my references so that whenever I write a program in command prompt and can easily search up for the API.

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean like an interactive console? If so can you not use an editor? Java programs still need to be compiled and executed.

Comment: Java isn't interpreted, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: can you explain how you are able to write program in command prompt ?

Comment: would be a cool task for you too: write an interactive console java program that can search and find through the java API, but why do you write "a program in command prompt"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for easy ways to remember the available functions, an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) will autocomplete the available functions as you type, so it should be easy to find them if that's what you want.

However,  the reference to the 'command prompt' is confusing... If you need language you can actually execute from the command prompt, you will need a language that has an interpreter and can import the Java APIs.  [Jython](http://www.jython.org), [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) or [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org) can all do that.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **NO**! there is no way to that. As explained above, you can use eclipse or Netbeans IDE and you have to press **Ctrl+space** to get the intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking for an easier way to program.  IDEs, such as [IntelliJ IDEA](http://jetbrains.com/idea), [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org), or [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) would be invaluable tools to have and master.

Also, it's just a fact of programming that, every now and then, we have to go back to the API for a thing or two.  There's really nothing really wrong with that.